# php foreach loop not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops

```
public function include_header( $h, $h_data ) {

    // Require header file
    if (isset($h) && !empty($h)) {
        $this->header_file = 'includes/header/'.$h;
    } else { return false; }

    // Pass optional array of parameters
    if (isset($h_data) && is_array($h_data) && !empty($h_data)) {

        // Loop through array & assign keys to appropriate class members
        foreach($h_data as $key => $val) {

            if ($key == 'doctype') { $this->doctype = $val; }
            if ($key == 'title') { $this->title = $val; }
            if ($key == 'meta') {
                // The meta key is should be an array in h_data
                // so, we'll have to loop through the meta array
                // in order to parse the individual meta elements.
                foreach($key as $meta_key => $meta_val) {
                    $this->error = $meta_key;
                }

            }

        }

    } else { return false; }

}
```

I'm trying to loop through a multidimensional array, where I have the following variable...

$h_data['meta']['individual_element']

I'm trying to loop through the 'meta', so I can access each individual value, but I'm having trouble.  Please help!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your nested for each should walk over $val not $key

Comment: Is the foreach loop not working correctly or do you need help looping through multi-dimensional array? What problem is it that your having?

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach($key as $meta_key => $meta_val) {
    $this->error = $meta_key;
}
```

... should be

```
foreach($val as $meta_key => $meta_val) {
    $this->error = $meta_key;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 if ($key == 'meta') {
                // The meta key is should be an array in h_data
                // so, we'll have to loop through the meta array
                // in order to parse the individual meta elements.
                foreach($val as $meta_key => $meta_val) { //val not key
                    $this->error = $meta_key;
                }
```